# Wicd asks for password at login

Tags: systemd, manjaro, wicd

I'm using Linux Manjaro, and recently switched from the default network manager to `wicd`. The switch went smoothly, except whenever I login I need to enter my password twice - once for the display manager, and once for "Wicd needs to access your network cards".

I tried the following fixes to resolve my problem:

- [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317157/177108) (except the package - it doesn't exist on manjaro)
- Fiddling with the `/lib/systemd/system/wicd.service` file by changing `After=syslog.target` to `After=syslog.target dbus.service` and different things like that.
- [This link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd#D-Bus_connection_error_message)

Nothing works - it still asks for a password. I suspect DBUS is the culprit here, but I don't know what to do.

So what do I do?

Comment: Are your trying this solution https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/wicd#D-Bus_connection_error_message ?

Comment: @GAD3R Tried, didn't work, added to the failed attempts list. :(